# properties, such as StartupForm, ChangeAppIconFrmR... erroring with "Property Not Found"

Tags: vba, ms-access

i have the code below, it sets a bunch of properties based on various tables
startup form, toolbars, shift bypass, etc

it worked fine for months, now, all of a sudden, all my dbs are opening with errors (so, corruption can't be the cause)
what's weird is that it works fine on a different computer
what can be wrong with the one that errors? i restarted

it errors at
s = CurrentDb.Properties(sPropName).Name

here's all 3 functions

```
Sub sbSetStartupOptions()
    Dim bOn             As Boolean
     
    SetOption "Auto Compact", True
    SetOption "Show Hidden Objects", False
    SetOption "Show System Objects", False
    SetOption "Confirm Record Changes", True
    SetOption "Confirm Document Deletions", True
    SetOption "Confirm Action Queries", True
    SetOption "Default Open Mode for Databases", 0 'shared
    SetOption "ShowWindowsInTaskbar", False
    
    sbAppIcon
    
    Dim vrAppName As String
    Dim vrStartupForm As String
    
    vrStartupForm = DLookup("StartupForm", "zAppSettings", "AppSettingsID=1")
    fnSetDatabaseProperty "StartupForm", 1, vrStartupForm
    
    vrAppName = DLookup("AppName", "zAppSettings", "AppSettingsID=1")
    fnChangeAppNameCurrentDB (vrAppName)
    
    fnSetDatabaseProperty "StartupShowStatusBar", 1, True '1=dbBoolean
    
    bOn = fnIsDev
    fnSetDatabaseProperty "AllowShortcutMenus", 1, bOn
    fnSetDatabaseProperty "StartupShowDBWindow", 1, bOn
    fnSetDatabaseProperty "AllowToolbarChanges", 1, bOn
    fnSetDatabaseProperty "AllowBreakIntoCode", 1, bOn
    fnSetDatabaseProperty "AllowSpecialKeys", 1, bOn
    fnSetDatabaseProperty "AllowBypassKey", 1, bOn
    fnSetDatabaseProperty "AllowFullMenus", 1, bOn
    fnSetDatabaseProperty "AllowBuiltinToolbars", 1, bOn
    Application.SetHiddenAttribute acTable, "zLockReleaseDatabase", Not bOn
        
End Sub

Function fnSetDatabaseProperty(ByVal sPropName As String, Optional ByVal lngPropType As Long, Optional vPropValue As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim s As String, bCreate As Boolean

    On Error Resume Next
    
    If CurrentProject.ProjectType = acADP Then
        s = CurrentProject.Properties(sPropName).Name
    Else
        s = CurrentDb.Properties(sPropName).Name
    End If
    
    If Err.Number > 0 Then bCreate = True
    
    On Error GoTo P_Error

    If bCreate Then
        If Not IsMissing(vPropValue) Then
            If CurrentProject.ProjectType = acADP Then
                CurrentProject.Properties.Add sPropName, vPropValue
            Else
                If lngPropType = 0 Then lngPropType = varType(vPropValue)
                CurrentDb.Properties.Append CurrentDb.CreateProperty(sPropName, lngPropType, vPropValue)
            End If
        End If
    Else
        If IsMissing(vPropValue) Then
            If CurrentProject.ProjectType = acADP Then
                CurrentProject.Properties.Remove sPropName
            Else
                CurrentDb.Properties.Delete sPropName
            End If
        Else
            If CurrentProject.ProjectType = acADP Then
                CurrentProject.Properties(sPropName).Value = vPropValue
            Else
                CurrentDb.Properties(sPropName).Value = vPropValue
            End If
        End If
    End If
    
    If Not CurrentProject.ProjectType = acADP Then
        CurrentDb.Properties.Refresh
    End If
    
    fnSetDatabaseProperty = True

P_Exit:
    Exit Function
P_Error:
    'GetError Err.Number, Err.description, Erl, CurrentObjectName, "SetDatabaseProperty"
    Resume P_Exit
End Function

Function fnSetProperties(strPropName As String, varPropType As Variant, varPropValue As Variant) As Integer

    On Error GoTo Err_SetProperties

    Dim db As DAO.database, prp As DAO.Property

    Set db = CurrentDb
    db.Properties(strPropName) = varPropValue
    fnSetProperties = True
    Set db = Nothing

Exit_SetProperties:
    Exit Function

Err_SetProperties:
    If Err = 3270 Then                           'Property not found
        Set prp = db.CreateProperty(strPropName, varPropType, varPropValue)
        db.Properties.Append prp
        Resume Next
    Else
        fnSetProperties = False
        MsgBox "SetProperties", Err.Number, Err.Description
        Resume Exit_SetProperties
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You understand that attempting to reference a property which does not exist triggers error #3270, *"Property not found."*  And you expect to suppress the display of that error message when you include `On Error Resume Next` before referencing the property.

However, although your code includes `On Error Resume Next` before `s = CurrentDb.Properties(sPropName).Name`, Access still displayed the error message whenever property `sPropName` did not exist.

The only way I could find to replicate that behavior is by setting Access' Error Trapping option to *"Break on All Errors"*  With that setting, the following simple procedure displays the *"Property not found"* error message despite `On Error Resume Next` --- the same situation you're dealing with.  It appears *"Break on All Errors"* trumps `On Error Resume Next`.

```vb
Public Sub test_04()
    Dim s As String
    Dim sPropName As String

    sPropName = "BOGUS" ' no such property exists in my database
    On Error Resume Next
    s = CurrentDb.Properties(sPropName).Name
End Sub
```

If I change my Error Trapping option to either *"Break in Class Module"* or  *"Break on Unhandled Errors"*, that procedure does not display the error message.   With those options, the behavior is determined by `On Error Resume Next` --- the code continues on without displaying an error message.

Comment: hi again :) i will try but i'm wondering why it all of a sudden stopped working on azure remote computers after working close to a year. and it works fine on my regular computer. and it's not just startupform that fails, starts, with  ChangeAppIconFrmR..., after i comment it out, startupform failes, and i'm sure, if i comment out startupform, the next one will fail as well. but i will try your fix anyway, thank you!

Comment: Hi Natalie.  Not sure we're on the same page.  Maybe just add the following line to the beginning of `sbSetStartupOptions()` and check whether it changes anything: `Application.SetOption "Error Trapping", 2`

Comment: hey, what i'm saying is, that i'm, of course, interested in fixing this error. but i'm equally interested in understanding why it works on one computer and not the other. and why it worked for many months on this computer as well, and then, one day, all my databases on this remote azure computer started giving errors "property not found". the reason why it matters is because some of my clients also remote through azure (if i'm right and it only errors on remote azure) and if this stopped working one day with no explanation, something else might, one day, stop working for them as well.

Comment: continued, ran out of space.  i'd love to try to figure out why on some computers access dbs can start erroring yet the same dbs dont error on another computer.

Comment: *"... why it works on one computer and not the other"*  Have you compared the Error Trapping option on those computers?  Are they the same or different?

Comment: the same :( i set it up the same everywhere, to break on all errors. is that what you're asking? and i'm stumped why it it worked and then just stopped

Comment: Please perform a quick test.  On a computer with one of the databases which gives you the problem, add the following line to the beginning of `sbSetStartupOptions()` and check whether it changes anything: `Application.SetOption "Error Trapping", 2`  When you test after making that change, do you still see the "property not found" error message?

Comment: it works lol. and thats a solution, im marking it as complete but i'd still love to know why it suddenly stopped working

Comment: Your situation was more confusing because you got inconsistent results across a mix of different computers and databases.  Although apparently you had "Break on All Errors" as your Error Trapping option for all of them, some did not present the "Property not found" error.  That only way I can see that happening is if  `CurrentDb.Properties(sPropName).Name` never encountered a property which didn't exist in those non-problematic databases.  So they worked when all the properties were found and "stopped working" when any property was not found.  That's my best and only guess!

Comment: yeah, thats what confuses me. why did it work? and (need to test some more on different computers) so far it seems that only azure remote computers mess up. just weird, i hate these types of issues, where things work and then they stop. makes me unsure of anything i develop if it can just break one day. anyway, huge thank you for your help and patience. you've saved me so many times over the years :) i don't know why you spend your time here but i'm forever grateful

Comment: You're welcome, Natalie.  Something I didn't mention before: I never use "Break on All Error" in a production database, and hardly ever if not yet production status.  See what Luke Chung says about that option: [Basic Error Handling](https://www.fmsinc.com/tpapers/vbacode/debug.asp#BasicErrorHandling) (the paragraph just below the Options screen shot)

Comment: thank you, will definitely read. i will start turning it off for production but while developing, it's really helpful to me. but maybe i'm misunderstanding what Break On All Errors does and there's a better way. i like being able to step through the errors